# How when works in aurelia validation

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm trying to do conditional validation but I'm not sure how `when` works:
How would I add my condition?

```
    // Validate fields
    ValidationRules
      .ensure('name')
        .required().withMessage(this.i18n.tr('validation1'))
      .ensure('type')
        .required().withMessage(this.i18n.tr('validation3'))
      .ensure('manufacturer')
        .required().when(()=>{this.isRequired()}).withMessage(this.i18n.tr('validation4'))
      .on(this.details.values);
  }

  isRequired(){
    return this.details.values['type'] == 3;
  }
```

Comment: `.when(() => this.isRequired())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As dfsq pointed out you need to remove the curly braces because,

`() =>  this.isRequired()` is equivalent to `() => { return this.isRequired() }` and not `() => { this.isRequired() }`

[More on Arrow Functions on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)